# .HTaccess Subdirectory Redirect to Different Server

Tags: php, .htaccess, amazon-ec2

I'm about to start running three different environments of our PHP application - Development, Staging and Production. Some of our customers will get access to Staging to help us test new features with real customers before it his production.
Our application is running on AWS EC2 though an elastic load balancer using HTTPS only. I need a way to allow users to go to https://mydomain.com/staging and be redirected to the staging environment (would still show https://mydomain.com/staging in the address bar, but they'd be getting content from a different set of servers). There will be some code in Staging that will ensure their account has been approved for Staging access and will allow them in or redirect them to the main application.

I can't seem to figure out how to write this in .htaccess. I've tried a number of things I've found online and haven't gotten it to work. I am beginning to think it may make more sense to have a real directory even in the production environment called 'staging' and have an index.php file inside that checks their account and redirects them based on the result.

However, I'd like to avoid having to purchase another SSL certificate for this, so instead of using a subdomain for staging, I'd like to use a virtual directory. Does that make sense?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the use of .htaccess in your httpd config file (you can do so by finding the line in your conf file that has AllowOverride None and change it AllowOverride All) and then place a .htaccess in a folder in your html folder called staging with the following line

```
Redirect /staging http://whereverYourStagingEnvoIs
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a subdomain instead of a subdirectory, `staging.mydomain.com`

Then in your host records for `mydomain.com` you could point `staging` to whatever server you like.